# ShortCode Wordpress doesnt work

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have a shortcode that I put in my post but somehow it doent execute for some reasong. Here is the code I have:

`short-code.php`:

```
add_shortcode('teammate',function($atts){
            $classes=$atts['country'];
            $imgUrl=$atts['img'];
            $name=$atts['name'];
            $description=$atts['description'];
            echo '
            <div class="member "'.$classes.'>
                <div class="member-img">
                    <img src="'.$imgUrl.'">
                </div>
                <div class="member-desc">
                    <h1>'.$name.'</h1>
                    <p>'.$description.'</p>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"> </div>

            </div>
            ';
        });
```

Here is how I include the file in `functions.php`:

```
$includes = array(
                'includes/theme-options.php',           // Options panel settings and custom settings
                'includes/theme-functions.php',         // Custom theme functions
                'includes/theme-actions.php',           // Theme actions & user defined hooks
                'includes/theme-comments.php',          // Custom comments/pingback loop
                'includes/theme-js.php',                // Load JavaScript via wp_enqueue_script
                'includes/sidebar-init.php',            // Initialize widgetized areas
                'includes/theme-widgets.php',           // Theme widgets
                'includes/short-code.php',              // Custom shortcode file for side menu
                'includes/team.php'                     //team shortcode
                );
```

and here is what i put in my page:

```
<div class="outer-members">
        <div class="inner-members">
[teammate name="Darko Petkovski" img="http://myurl.com/myimage.jpg" description="test" country="mc"]

        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the code is working ok, but the only problem is that shortcode isn't executing outside wp.

Comment: Hi, first of all, it seems that your answer is really added info about the question, so maybe you should edit it into your question. And second of all, what do you mean `shortcode isn't executing outside wp`?

Comment: Do you mean outside your post, somewhere in the template file?

Comment: I have a html page outside wp but on the same server. So I've make that work by getting the post content by post id, and then by using `do_shortcode()` for post content I managet to get the shortcode executing.